# c++/cli : make public interface method to internal in class implementation

Tags: inheritance, c++-cli

I have an interface in CLI which  has one method. I am implementing this interface in one class but i don't want interface method to accessible in C# so i made it internal in class declaration. but it gives compilation error **must provide an implementation for the interface method**. I have provided method implementation to all in .cpp file of class.

```
public interface class BASE
{
  void foo(String^ str);
}
```

Class:

```
public ref class Test: public BASE
{
public:
//some public method

internal:
void foo(String^ str); // This gives error.
}
```

I don't want to expose `foo()` to C#. How to do this ? I tried making it private but got same error.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clumsy, not entirely uncommon for the C++/CLI compiler.  But it objects against your attempt to make the method inaccessible.  Because it isn't *really* inaccessible, the user of your class can trivially bypass it and do this:

```
var obj = new Test();
var itf = (BASE)obj;
itf.foo("Fooled");
```

An inevitable side-effect of you making the interface public.  The only way to stop client code from using the interface is by making it *internal*, drop the *public* keyword.  Either way, you can make the method directly visible by using an *explicit implementation* of the interface method:

```
internal:
    virtual void bar(String^ str) = BASE::foo;
```

Comment: I can't change any thing in base interface as it is used by other classes also for whom `foo()` should be exposed or public :( any other solution ?

Comment: A solution to what?  I showed you how to hide the method, that's as good as it is going to get.